# MongoDB write lock every n seconds during data import

Tags: mongodb, aws, sharding

I am experiencing an issue with a data import in a sharded cluster and I'd like some help to investigate and maybe find where the bottleneck is in my cluster.

So I'm hosting a sharded cluster (3 shards) on AWS EC2 (not Atlas).

Each shard is a 3 members replica set with 1 primary (r4.xlarge) and 2 secondaries (r4.large). Config servers are c4.large and is of course replica set too.

- r4.xlarge are 30,5G Ram, 4vCPU
- r4.large are 15,5G Ram, 2vCPU

WiredTiger cache setting is default one, so 50% of RAM for both primaries and secondaries.

Secondaries are less powerful than primaries and have a priority of 5 (primaries have a priority of 10) because they are used as a data replica only for durability (almost no read on them except at given time of the day for metrics computation).

On each shard members, data, journal and logs directories are mounted each on different EBS volumes (GP2) :

- data : 600 iops
- journal : 200 iops
- log : 100 iops

I have another machine on EC2 (m4.large) running an ETL process in python (processing a CSV of 85M lines) and importing them in sets, in a collection of 10M+ documents. This is not a mongoimport or mongorestore process but a custom script (applying transformation to data before inserting), and I am not doing imports using multiple threads or processes in parallel.

MongoDB version is 3.4.10, storage engine is WiredTiger, journaling is enabled, and default write concern is {w:1}.

Balancing and balancer are stopped, and I do not run any other operation in parallel.

Updates are done in bulks (1000 operations at a time), using $addToSet, and everything is working fine BUT every n operations, there is some kind of lock and it slows down the whole process.

My application logs every write operation, and here is a sample :

```
2018-04-26 20:58:12,704 [INFO] Batch #15916 | 0.93s | 1076r/s [Ins:0, Fnd:1000, Mdf:1000, Ups:0]
2018-04-26 20:58:13,352 [INFO] Batch #15917 | 0.65s | 1543r/s [Ins:0, Fnd:1000, Mdf:1000, Ups:0]
2018-04-26 20:58:14,627 [INFO] Batch #15918 | 1.27s | 784r/s [Ins:0, Fnd:1000, Mdf:1000, Ups:0] <<< this happens every 10 or 15 chunks, roughly every 12 to 15 seconds
2018-04-26 20:58:15,601 [INFO] Batch #15919 | 0.97s | 1026r/s [Ins:0, Fnd:1000, Mdf:1000, Ups:0]
2018-04-26 20:58:16,556 [INFO] Batch #15920 | 0.95s | 1047r/s [Ins:0, Fnd:1000, Mdf:1000, Ups:0]
```

When I change the write concern and set it to {w:0}, it's even worse (same bulk size, same script):

```
2018-04-26 21:24:11,280 [INFO] Batch #0014 | 0.34s | 2899r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:11,624 [INFO] Batch #0015 | 0.34s | 2909r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:11,981 [INFO] Batch #0016 | 0.36s | 2794r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:12,331 [INFO] Batch #0017 | 0.35s | 2863r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:20,281 [INFO] Batch #0018 | 7.95s | 125r/s  <<<< Here
2018-04-26 21:24:20,642 [INFO] Batch #0019 | 0.36s | 2771r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:20,991 [INFO] Batch #0020 | 0.35s | 2869r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:21,335 [INFO] Batch #0021 | 0.34s | 2906r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:21,683 [INFO] Batch #0022 | 0.35s | 2876r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:30,176 [INFO] Batch #0023 | 8.49s | 117r/s  <<<< Here
2018-04-26 21:24:30,524 [INFO] Batch #0024 | 0.35s | 2876r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:30,866 [INFO] Batch #0025 | 0.34s | 2925r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:31,221 [INFO] Batch #0026 | 0.35s | 2819r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:31,567 [INFO] Batch #0027 | 0.35s | 2891r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:39,747 [INFO] Batch #0028 | 8.18s | 122r/s  <<<< Here
2018-04-26 21:24:40,100 [INFO] Batch #0029 | 0.35s | 2830r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:40,444 [INFO] Batch #0030 | 0.34s | 2908r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:40,783 [INFO] Batch #0031 | 0.34s | 2950r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:41,135 [INFO] Batch #0032 | 0.35s | 2844r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:48,876 [INFO] Batch #0033 | 7.74s | 129r/s  <<<< Here
2018-04-26 21:24:49,239 [INFO] Batch #0034 | 0.36s | 2758r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:49,596 [INFO] Batch #0035 | 0.36s | 2800r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:49,944 [INFO] Batch #0036 | 0.35s | 2877r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:50,297 [INFO] Batch #0037 | 0.35s | 2830r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:58,135 [INFO] Batch #0038 | 7.84s | 127r/s  <<<< Here
2018-04-26 21:24:58,498 [INFO] Batch #0039 | 0.36s | 2757r/s
2018-04-26 21:24:58,844 [INFO] Batch #0040 | 0.35s | 2889r/s
```

It looks like some kind of "commit" every n seconds or n operations, but I looked at the metrics on AWS and it does not seem to be a problem with disk iops.

Sample document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("58de480d7ae97f6817f4a36d"), 
    "external_id" : "123456789",
    "code" : {...}, 
    "date_in" : ISODate("2015-12-20T01:00:00.000+0100"), 
    "custom" : {...}, 
    "address" : {...},
    "orders" : [
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
        {...},
        {...}
    ],
    "mailing" : {
        "sent" : [
            {
                "c" : NumberInt(0), 
                "d" : ISODate("2018-04-20T02:01:00.000+0200"), 
                "i" : NumberInt(5796), 
                "r" : NumberInt(0), 
                "t" : NumberInt(2), 
                "x" : NumberInt(600030925), 
                "y" : "722"
            }, 
            {
                "c" : NumberInt(0), 
                "d" : ISODate("2017-12-26T01:01:00.000+0100"), 
                "i" : NumberInt(5796), 
                "r" : NumberInt(0), 
                "t" : NumberInt(2), 
                "x" : NumberInt(600009477), 
                "y" : "443"
            }
        ],
        "delivered":[{...},{...},{...}],
        "opened":[{...},{...},{...}],
        "opened":[{...},{...},{...}],
        "clicked":[{...},{...},{...}],
        "bounces":[{...},{...},{...}]
    }
}
```

The process adds new elements to arrays mailing.sent, mailing.delivered, mailing.opened, etc. using $addToSet.

I know that secondaries are more stressed than the primary because the oplog records an update of the whole array and not just the $addToSet operation (there is a ticket on JIRA about that).

Database volume is growing as I import the data (about 60Go of data for the given collection), as well as document size.

Has anyone experienced anything like that and could point me in the right direction to solve this issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: There are some questions that would need clarification: 1) What is the size of your RAM, 2) What is the size of your WiredTiger cache, 3) Is this still happening with MongoDB 3.4.14, 4) Why are the two secondaries weaker than the primary, 5) Do you have custom priorities in the replica set setting, 6) Do you use multiple threads doing import, 7) Please show an example document and what is the shard key

Comment: I edited the question with the clarification you requested. And I didn't test on 3.4.14 but as I read the changelog, I don't see why it wouldn't ?

Comment: There might be some issues that was fixed in 3.4.14, so I would encourage you to try the newest version if feasible. This way, we can be certain that it's not due to some old issue that was fixed. On another note, have you tried making the WiredTiger cache smaller? E.g. try a relatively small value of 1 GB and see if the "stalling" persists?

Comment: I have a development shard (on local) that I can easily upgrade to 3.4.14 and test on. I first have to check that the behavior can be reproduced. Concerning your side note: how would reducing WT cache help ?

Comment: It is possible that the "stalls" are due to WT trying to write the dirty part of the cache to disk (which was directly related to the configured size of the WT cache), but the disk is not responding fast enough for WT's needs, thus WT was forced to wait. While WT was waiting, all upstream processes would in turn would have to wait as well, leading to "stalls". Making the cache smaller could result in less data to be written all at once, hopefully making the stalls disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am going to try to reduce the cache on the development shard and run a before/after test. However, I wonder what are the side effects of reducing the cache in terms of querying the DB, mostly because I have massive indexes too and I need them to be in memory (is it in the WT cache ?)

Comment: Well according to the doc (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#to-what-size-should-i-set-the-wiredtiger-internal-cache), WT internal cache is used to store indexes, and 1Gb is far from enough. Still, I am going to try if it's a problem with cache size (although I don't get what is the dirty part of it yet)

Comment: So I ran mongostat against one of the primary in the shard, and "stalls" actually match the moments where "flushes" happen. The dirty part of the cache is moving between 2% and 4%, with cache usage of 80%.

Comment: Yes that was what I suspected. WT will keep dirty percentage to below 5%, and the overall cache usage below 80% under normal conditions. The stalls were the result of the disk trying to keep up with the volume of incoming data, so the solution is to either to provision a faster disk, make the cache smaller, or regulate the volume of incoming data. In terms of cache size, I agree that you would need to find a balance between minimizing the impact of those flushes, while still have enough size to service reads (I was just throwing the 1GB number as an example).

Comment: Well, Kudos to you Kevin, maybe you should turn one of this comment to an acceptable answer. Thank you for your input, I know where to dig to try and reduce the stalls.

Comment: Done. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stalls you're seeing sounds like the result of the disk trying to keep up with the volume of incoming data. That is, it was caused by WiredTiger waiting for disk flushes to finish. While WiredTiger was waiting, all upstream processes would in turn have to wait as well, leading to observable stalls.

By default in MongoDB 3.6.4, WiredTiger will try to keep dirty percentage (size of modified data in the cache relative to configured cache size) to below 5% of configured cache size, and the overall cache usage below 80% of configured cache size. The default cache size is described in [WiredTiger memory use](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#memory-use).

Once the percentages goes beyond these numbers, WiredTiger will try much harder by making application threads that wants to do an operation in WiredTiger (such as the threads doing your inserts) to help with cache eviction (which could involve flushing to disk) before it's allowed to do the work. This acts as a built-in throttling mechanism to ensure that the storage engine and the disk are not extremely overwhelmed by incoming work.

Possible solution include:

- Provision a disk that is able to write faster.
- Configure a smaller WiredTiger cache, making the 5% number small enough to not overwhelm the disk's capabilities.
- Regulate the volume of incoming data from the application side.
- Some combination of the three points above.

In terms of a suitable cache size for your workload, I agree that you would need to find a balance between minimizing the impact of those flushes, while still having enough size to service reads.